# How to log failed queries when using Eloquent as an ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim

Is there a way to log failed queries in the database in Slim when using Eloquent as an ORM?
I have written a listener to log queries, however it only logs successful queries and I get exceptions for failed queries without anything being logged.
Below is my listener code:

```
$capsule->getConnection()->listen(function ($query) use ($headers) {

$values =array(
            $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
            $query->sql,
            json_encode($query->bindings),
            $headers[HeaderKey::USER_ID],
            $headers[HeaderKey::IP_ADDRESS,
            $headers[HeaderKey::SYS_KEY],
            $query->time,
            $query->connection->getDatabaseName(),
            $query->connection->getConfig('username'),
            $query->connection->getConfig('host'),
            );
            $t = "`SysDbLog_" . date('Y-m-d') . "`";
            DB::connection('logdb')
            ->insert("insert DELAYED into $t (page,query,SerializedParam,UserID,IPAddress,SysCode,ExecuteTime,DBName,DBUser, DBHost, WebServer) 
            values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 2), '@', -1)))", $values);
        });
$capsule->bootEloquent();

    return $capsule;}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried to add a Middleware that catches all Eloquent specific exceptions and log that with a logger like Monolog?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database `ORM` such as `Eloquent` to connect your SlimPHP application to a database. You can just working with `LoggerInterface`. More information you can find in official site.

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/database-eloquent.html

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to catch and handel PDOExceptions in SlimErrorHandler or as you set manage all the log things through LoggerInterface.

Comment: Yes you can do it without problem, if you need you can accept answer.